# SIGSEGV Error in String manipulation using pointers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void) {
    int t, n, i, j;
    char dir[41][52];
    char right[] = "Right";
    char left[] = "Left";
    char *p = NULL, storeDir[10], *k = NULL;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        fflush(stdin);
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            gets(dir[i]);
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        i = n - 1;
        k = dir[i];
        j = 0;
        p = strchr(dir[i], 'o');
        while(*k != ' ') {
            storeDir[j] = *k;
            k++;
            j++;
        }
        storeDir[j] = '\0';
        printf("Begin ");
        printf("%s\n", p);
        for(i = n - 2; i  >= 0; i--) {
            if(strcmp(storeDir, right) == 0) {
                printf("Left ");
            }
            else if(strcmp(storeDir, left) == 0) {
                printf("Right ");
            }
            k = dir[i];
            j = 0;
            p = strchr(dir[i], 'o');
            while(*k != ' ') {
                storeDir[j] = *k;
                k++;
                j++;
            }
            storeDir[j] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", p);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a code which just takes in some strings and prints out by manipulating them with pointers. It runs fine on my computer, but when i run it on  http://ideone.com/ it gives a SIGSEGV Error. 
I think it's due to some invalid pointer reference. But, I'm not able to figure out where i go wrong. Could someone please point that out to me?
Here is a sample test case for the program :

```
4
Begin on Road A
Right on Road B
Right on Road C
Left on Road D
```

TIA

Comment: Add `-Wall` to your compiler flags and think a bit about the messages you see.

Comment: The same coding competition as mohitce, but at least using long variable names. Don't you guys go steal each other's ideas now.

Comment: How do i add compiler flags ? I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express

Answer (score 3):

1. You're using `gets()`: [Don't do that](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/gets.html).
2. You're not checking the error codes; if `scanf()` doesn't receive data in *exactly* the right format, then `n` won't have the correct value.
3. You're not checking the error codes: when `strchr()` doesn't find a `o` then it returns NULL
4. Your "test data" doesn't have the correct data. Combining this with no error checking is a recipe for disaster.

Here's where it goes wrong: You do a `scanf()` to load `t` which isn't reflected by your "test data" (which would indicate 4 records when in fact only one is listed). The next character is a *Carriage Return* which `scanf()` eats but doesn't continue.

The next `scanf()` to read `n` gets the next character, a *Newline*, which isn't a digit so it fails.

Now we've got some random number (whatever was on the stack) in `n` and we call `gets()` which loads into some random `dir[]` slot some amount of data: the character still on the input queue is a *Newline* so this returns an empty string.

When `strchr()` fails to find the `o` in `"on"` that you expect, it returns NULL, which we then dereference in `storeDir`, which is where your program crashes: a null pointer exception. Unless of course, you get lucky and `gets()` overwrites some data, or your stack contains a number small enough to fit into `dir`.

If I give your program "correct" data, such as:

```
1 4 Begin on Road A
Right on Road B
Right on Road C
Left on Road D
```

your program completes successfully.

Comment: +1 for patience and the holiday spirit.